# Question regarding variable notation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, notation

I have a variable $A_i \in \{ A_1, A_2, ..., A_n \}$ which denotes a worker, and another variable $B_k \in \{ location_1, location_2,..., location_m\}$, which denotes a location.

Due to the model of the problem I'm working on (which unfortunately cannot change), I have to denote a worker-location pair $(A_i, B_k)$ with the notation  $A_{ik}$, but $k$ should be equal to the value of $B_k$, not just equal to its index. For example,   $A_{2location_1}$ denotes the worker-location pair $(A_2, location_1)$.

I could state that $A_{ik} = (A_i, B_k)$ such that $k = B_k \in \{ location_1, location_2,..., location_m\}$.

However, this could be a bit confusing. For instance, in the case of $A_{2location_1}$, it means that $k=B_k=location_1$ (and therefore $B_{location_1}=location_1$).

Is there a better (more elegant way) to express this, or could this approach be considered acceptable in an academic setting?

Please note that it is very important to stick to the $A_{ik}$ notation, as explained above.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to change the set $\{a,b,c,d,\dots,z\}$?  If not, then it is also confusing that both $k$ and $n$ are members of this set: $\{a,b,c,d,\dots,k,\ell,m,n,\dots,z\}$.

Comment: Yes, actually each element of the set is the name of a location. I wrote it that way for the sake of simplicity, but it creates more confusion. I will edit it in the question.